# Razor 9DOF SMD Capacitor replacing

Tags: sensors, electronics

I just bought This IMU a while ago, and when I reached the point where I wanna connect it, I noticed that one of the capacitors have been removed by accedint, and since it took too long to check the product, I won't get to replace it or get any refund, so my question, how can I replace that SMD capacitor?
P.S. I have some Ultrasonic sensors might have the same SMD capacitors that I can take off and replace with if anyone can help.

[image: The circled capacitor is the one]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for C22,  0.1uF capacitor, connected to smooth the 3.3v from the regulator. If you are not using the battery connector, you can probably just leave it out.

You could just get a capacitor with leads and connect it somewhere between 3.3v and ground. You can use the ISP header (2x3 holes on the right) for this. I think it's the top-right and bottom-right pin.

Answer (score 0):

You are on a tough road. I hope someone can give you specifics.  Normally you would able to identify the capacitor from its parts designation, but that board does not have any. So you will have to match the schematic (assuming spark fun provides one) to the board layout to figure out what it is.  The cost of the part is probably over a penny, maybe even 2 cents. In other words, not an issue.

It will require hot air to desolder one from another board and to solder this one on. Someone might be able to do it with a fine tip solder  pencil, but not likely.

Bottom line; find someone who has experience repairing boards, or order another one. Amazon has breakout boards for the 6050 for $6. But I see this one has Serial, and a magnetometer, so it is not quite the same. But depending on what you plan to do with it, it could work.

Comment: C22,  0.1uF capacitor, connected to smooth the 3.3v from the regulator.

Comment: If you don't care about the donor board, you can just get a sharp knife and get under the copper, and lift it from the board. Then use a soldering iron to remove the bit of copper trace. It might take a couple of tries, so first try on some other components first.

Comment: The problem is I can't order another one, it would take over 1 month to reach me, someone else told me that I can power it through the pins, is that possible if I read it's datacheat or not?
I'm using it to stabalize a quadcopter, that why I can't risk not knowing too well, coz if I get wrong data it would waste alot of time to figure that out :\

Comment: Yes, @gerben answer sounded reasonable (I upvoted it)

Answer (score 0):

Try using two soldering pencils, one in each hand. makes it easy to remove the capacitor from the donor board.